# str_replace + regular expression

Tags: php, regex

I have:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43242&cat=aa&id=342342
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43242&cat=aa&body=434&id=232
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43242&cat=aa&call=2323&id=14143434
```

i would like receive:

this link without parameter id:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43242&cat=aa
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43242&cat=aa&body=434
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43242&cat=aa&call=2323
```

how this make with PHP? str_replace + regular expression?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
preg_replace('~&id=[0-9]+~', '', $str);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the [appropriate function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) for this, not regular expressions since URL's aren't regular.

You should then split the query part, which can be done with regular expressions, but I'd like to split on & and then filter out the ID part.

Comment: URLs aren't regular? That's news to me. Of course, I'm all for using the right method to accomplish something, but the claim that URLs are not a regular language is false as far as I can see.

Comment: how can i use this function in my example?

Comment: I misinterpreted based on the original question. What I meant to say is the order of the query parameters can vary. But simply replacing an '&id=[0-9]+' part when present can be done using regexes.

Comment: Good, because PHP's regexes were never regular either.